# Disable a relevant button in a default layout

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an Android application.

All the activities within my app have the same base layout, which is defined in the file "default_layout.xml". In each activities layout file, I use:

`<include layout="@layout/default_layout" android:id="@+id/include"/>`

to include the layout.

What I'm trying to do is disable the button in the default layout (make it unclickable and change it's alpha value to visually represent this) which is relevant to the activity which is currently open, to prevent the user opening another of the same activity. For example, I'd like to disable the "settings" button when the settings activity is created.

I can access the button via the code within the onCreate method, like so:

```
findViewById(R.id.saveButton).setEnabled(false);
findViewById(R.id.saveButton).setClickable(false);
findViewById(R.id.saveButton).setFocusable(false);
findViewById(R.id.saveButton).setAlpha(0.5f);
```

without any errors, however none of these methods actually work on the button.

Below is my default_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_open"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:id="@+id/openButton"
        android:textSize="16sp" android:background="#0A7D1F"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:textColor="#fff"/>

<Button android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_save"
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:background="#0A7D1F"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/openButton" android:textColor="#fff"
        android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:longClickable="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

<Button android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#0A7D1F"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fu3Button"/>

<Button android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_connect"
        android:id="@+id/connectButton"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#0A7D1F"
        android:textColor="#fff" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sendButton"/>

<Button android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_fu1"
        android:id="@+id/fu1Button"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fu2Button" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/openButton"
        android:background="#0A7D1F" android:textColor="#fff"/>

<Button android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_fu2"
        android:id="@+id/fu2Button" android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fu3Button"
        android:background="#0A7D1F" android:textColor="#fff"/>

<Button android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_fu3"
        android:id="@+id/fu3Button" android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fu2Button" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/saveButton"
        android:background="#0A7D1F" android:textColor="#fff"/>

<Button android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_settings"
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton" android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fu3Button" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/connectButton"
        android:background="#0A7D1F" android:textColor="#fff"
        android:onClick="openSettings" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you show the default_layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the 'default_layout.xml' file, to ensure the ID of the button you want is in fact 'saveButton'? What kind of buttons are these? Are they items in a menu, are the on the appbar, are they actual buttons?

Comment: Shouldn't matter the types of buttons, the methods that are being called are available on all `View` objects

Comment: Agreed, I should have simply asked to see the 'default_layout.xml' file instead.

Comment: Yeah, the id is correct. I have edited the OP to include the layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the background you are setting in each button.  This may be hiding the fact you are disabling etc.

Comment: Even if it was visually hidden, I can press the button and it opens another instance of it's relevant activity. This is what I'm trying to prevent.